# How large is a multitude?

Tags: word-usage, numbers

I was recently looking for an adjective to describe how many answers a question received after being bountied. One word I thought of was *multitude*.

> Initially my question didn't receive many answers. However, thanks to Lilienthal's generous bounty, I now have a ***multitude*** of answers to choose from.

[According to Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/multitude), a *multitude* refers to:

> 1. a great number; host:
>      *a multitude of friends.*
> 2. a great number of people gathered together; crowd; throng.
> 3. the state or character of being many; numerousness.
> 4. the multitude, the common people; the masses.
>
> <sub>[multitude](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/multitude). (n.d.). *Dictionary.com Unabridged*. Retrieved July 27, 2017</sub>

After some thought, I'm unsure whether *multitude* is an accurate term for this scenario. The aforementioned bounty attracted *seven* different answers to my question, which seems too small to be called a multitude.

**How large of a number does a multitude refer to?**

Comment: To say 7 answers is a multitude is speaking in hyperbole.

Comment: The **first listed** definition here (and I'm sure in most other dictionaries) is 'a great number / a host'. Thousands at least. One should be very careful that one doesn't assume that hyperbolic usage isn't going to lead to misconceptions (where it matters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like the answer to this question is relative to the context.

I use "multitude" when referring to an amount of something that is apparently *way* bigger than the normal amount. If the usual amount is only a few, having let's say 50 or 100 more items can be considered a great amount more. If the normal is a larger number, have 50 or 100 items would not be a shockingly large number. One way you can measure that is by thinking, when someone reads my sentence would their reaction be, "Wow, that is a huge number!"?

If the average amount of answers to a question is let's say 3, no one would view 4 more answers as *way* more than usually. If you, however, tell me that a question has 20 or 30 answers, my reaction would be that the question has a lot more answers that are normally provided and a lot more answers that are needed, so at that point I would say it is okay to use "multitude".

Answer (score 1):

I think multitude means a number too large to count.

Its closest synonyms would be crowd, throng. When you have a multitude of friends, you have so many you just can't keep track of the number. When you have a multitude of options, you have so many options, it would be a waste of time to count them.

Seven answers would not be a multitude.